# convert String index to Int

Tags: swift

I have a `UILabel` called `nihoshim` and the element in the last index is a number I want to increase. `alpha` is a collection of `UIButton`.

```swift
@IBAction func wordChoser(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let tag = sender.tag - 1
    var liel = nihoshim.text! 
    let index = Int(liel.endIndex) // error here
    var alephbet = ["א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","כ","ל","מ","נ","ס","ע","פ","צ","ק","ר","ש","ת"]
    if  gameLabel.text!.count <= 3 {
        gameLabel.text = gameLabel.text! + alephbet[alpha.index(after: tag) - 1]
        sender.isHidden = true
    } else if gameLabel.text!.count <= 3 {
        gameLabel.text = gameLabel.text! + alephbet[alpha.index(after: tag) - 1]
        sender.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'String.Index' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Comment: For arrays, `alephbet[alpha.index(after: tag) - 1]` should be the same as `alephbet[tag]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last character of a string you can use `suffix()`

```
str.suffix(1)
```

So in your code, replace `let index = Int(liel.endIndex)` with

```
guard let index = Int(liel.suffix(1)) else {
    return //or some error handling
}
```

Comment: but how to covert it to int?

Comment: Now the error is Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type 'inout Int'

Comment: @LHanohov First of all I assume you didn't use `guard` as I did in my answer since you have an optional Int and secondly I see nothing in your code that could generate that error. To me it looks like I have answered your question and this another issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just convert `String.Index` into a number.

The simplest way to do this, if we are talking about `endIndex`, is:

```
let index = liel.count
```

For other indices, this would be:

```
let string = "abcd"
let stringIndex: String.Index = string.endIndex
let index: Int = string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: stringIndex)
```

Comment: But how can I update the value of the number in the end index?

Comment: @LHanohov I don't understand what you want to do. `endIndex` is updated when you update the string, e.g. when you append or remove a character.

Answer (score 0):

As [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56522548/6162353) said you could use distance to be as below,

```
@IBAction func wordChoser(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let liel = nihoshim.text, let morning = gameLabel.text else {
            return
        }
        let tag: Int = sender.tag - 1
        let index: Int = liel.distance(from: liel.startIndex, to: liel.endIndex)
        var alephbet = ["א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","כ","ל","מ","נ","ס","ע","פ","צ","ק","ר","ש","ת"]
        if morning.count <= 3 {
            gameLabel.text = morning + alephbet[tag]
            gameLabel.text = morning + "\(index + tag)"
            sender.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```